# Why g_object_set throws an exception(vcruntime140.dll)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gstreamer

```
#pragma comment(lib, "gstreamer-1.0.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gobject-2.0.lib")


#include <iostream>
#include <gst/gst.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    gst_init( &argc, &argv );
    GstElement *source = nullptr;
    source = gst_element_factory_make("rtspsrc", "test_src");
    g_object_set(source, "location", "rtsp://192.168.10.24:554");
    std::cout << "End";

}
```

After `g_object_set(source, "location", "rtsp://192.168.10.24:554");` an exception occurs: **Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC26E9193C (vcruntime140.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000008000.** 
Function `gst_element_factory_make` returns not NULL. Why this exception throws?

Comment: *Function gst_element_factory_make returns not NULL.* -- Prove it by actually writing the code that tests for this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `if( source != NULL ) g_object_set(source, "location", "rtsp://192.168.10.24:554");` Exception is still throwing...

Comment: According to the documentation, you are not calling `g_object_set` [correctly](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set).  Where is the terminating NULL?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks! My mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation found [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set), the issue is that the `g_object_set` is a variable-argument function that requires you to put in the sentinel argument (in this case, `NULL`).

```
g_object_set(source, "location", "rtsp://192.168.10.24:554", NULL);
```

Not placing `NULL` means that the variable argument function does not know when the last argument is reached, thus is processing invalid data which causes the segmentation fault.